# C programming Structure Vector allocation

Tags: c

I have a structure in c and I want to allocate memory for an array of my structure,
for this I'd created a function.
The problem is that only first element of array is working.
If I do allocation in main, it is working.

Here is my code:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char* name;
}Car;

void read(Car**cars){
    int n,i;
    char name[50];

    printf("Cars:"); scanf("%i",&n);

    *cars = (Car*) malloc(n * sizeof(Car));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("\nCar Name[%i]: ",i);   scanf("%s",name);

       (*cars[i]).id   = i; //when i>0 then It crash here...
       (*cars[i]).name = (char*) malloc(strlen(name)+1);

        strcpy((*cars[i]).name, name);

        printf("Cars Name -> %s ", (*cars[i]).name);
    } 
}

int main() {
   Car *cars = NULL;
   read(&cars);

   return 0;
}
```

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Note: Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: Note: it is probably better anyway to do the allocation *outside* the `read` function: that way, you'll have the allocation *and* the deletion/freeing up in the same place.

Comment: `*car = (Car*) malloc(n * sizeof(Car));`
typo: should be `cars` right?

Comment: Run your code through valgrind; it will likely show you where your mistake is, and possibly more.

Comment: I changed the name when I posted here...is not typo thx

Comment: Note: In C you usually write 1 instruction by line, you should split your `printf/scanf` combos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(*cars)[i].id   = i; //when i>0 then It crash here...
```

This should work for you.

explanation:

you allocate `n` elements to the value of the pointer to the `cars` pointer.

but you try to derefference the value of the `i`th pointer to a `cars` element.

With my correction you derefference the firsts pointer's `i`th `cars` id. what is bad coded but should do what you want.

But what you probabbly want to do is asigning multiple pointers which at all point to a single car pointer instead ;)

than your crashing line could stay at it is.